# Большое количество множителей при факторизации N в RSA

Tags: python, rsa, факторизация, decrypt

Имеется зашифрованное сообщение и модуль :

```
c: 9074407119435549226216306717104313210750146895081726439798095976354600576814818348656600684713830051655944443364224597709641982342039946659987121376590618828822446965847273448794324003758131816407702456966504389655568712152599077538994030379567217702587542326383955580601916478060973206347266442527564009737910
n: 18086135173395641986123054725350673124644081001065528104355398467069161310728333370888782472390469310073117314933010148415971838393130403883412870626619053053672200815153337045022984003065791405742151350233540671714100052962945261324862393058079670757430356345222006961306738393548705354069502196752913415352527
```

При факторизации модуля выдается 42 множителя,подумав, что перемножив 21 множителей я получу *p* и перемножив остальные получу *q*, далее раз нету открытой экспоненты, я создал список экспонент с условием, что *e* *(1 < e<(p-1)(q-1))*, далее вычислив *d*, попытался расшифровать сообщение, но успехов не было, сделав факторизацию через, другой сервис получил четыре значения которые по формуле суммы квадратов возвращали исходный модуль *n = a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2*, но взяв по принципу *p = a^2+b^2 q = c^2+d^2*, тоже не вышло ничего, прошу не решить за меня данную задачу, а подсказать куда мыслить далее...

Comment: `я создал список экспонент с условием, что e (1 < e<(p-1)(q-1))` что это значит, вы перепробовали 1e300 экспонент? что значит не было успехов? каждая новая экспонента расшифрует `c` в свое сообщение.

Comment: не совсем, написал функцию для генерации *e* от 1 до 1000000, затем из них брал каждую, и вычислял *d*, а далее расшифровывал, тут суть не в этом, а в том как принять из столь большого количества множителей *p* и *q*, так как *d=modinv(e,phi)*. ну а phi будет разным, при различных *p* и *q*

Comment: Я не знаю, а почему вы решили, что задачка имеет разумное решение? Как по мне, то здесь очень много решений, возможно я что-то упускаю. Это как дать 16 байт зашифрованных AES-128, и сказать расшифровать. Всего 2^128 ключей, и ровно столько же расшированых сообщений, среди которых будет какой угодно текст.

Comment: Кстати, `(p-1)(q-1)` - эта формула верна только для `p q`  простых. Если мне не изменяет память, нужно брать `(p1-1)(p2-1)(p3-1)...` для каждого простого множителя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно вычислить правильное `φ(n)`, и взять стандартную публичную экспоненту (`65537`). Мой пример кода:

```
BigInteger[] factors = new[]
{
    new BigInteger(16904777),
    new BigInteger(17673199),
    new BigInteger(17730961),
    new BigInteger(17901463),
    new BigInteger(18145913),
    new BigInteger(18313601),
    new BigInteger(18646361),
    new BigInteger(19459483),
    new BigInteger(20010041),
    new BigInteger(20013121),
    new BigInteger(20197313),
    new BigInteger(20390129),
    new BigInteger(21321539),
    new BigInteger(21647243),
    new BigInteger(21891889),
    new BigInteger(22050221),
    new BigInteger(22576643),
    new BigInteger(22685197),
    new BigInteger(23554169),
    new BigInteger(24525821),
    new BigInteger(24946057),
    new BigInteger(24996157),
    new BigInteger(25671797),
    new BigInteger(25808239),
    new BigInteger(25963459),
    new BigInteger(27138691),
    new BigInteger(27289543),
    new BigInteger(27409927),
    new BigInteger(27606707),
    new BigInteger(27739163),
    new BigInteger(28863719),
    new BigInteger(29488469),
    new BigInteger(29511773),
    new BigInteger(30342329),
    new BigInteger(30580789),
    new BigInteger(31696261),
    new BigInteger(31703933),
    new BigInteger(31737131),
    new BigInteger(31881917),
    new BigInteger(33098557),
    new BigInteger(33322589),
    new BigInteger(33381329),
};

var phi = BigInteger.One;
foreach (var factor in factors)
    phi *= factor - 1;

var e = new BigInteger(65537);
var d = BigInteger.ModularInverse(e, phi);

var cipher = BigInteger.Parse("9074407119435549226216306717104313210750146895081726439798095976354600576814818348656600684713830051655944443364224597709641982342039946659987121376590618828822446965847273448794324003758131816407702456966504389655568712152599077538994030379567217702587542326383955580601916478060973206347266442527564009737910");
var plain = BigInteger.ModularExponentiation(cipher, d, n);

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plain.ToBytes(ByteOrder.BigEndian)));
```

Получается такой текст:

```
timctf{mUlt1_PriM3_rS4_c0ULD_B3_DAngEr0us}
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение, но я хотел дойти до этого сам и уже дошел, увидев подсказку в комментариях выше.

Comment: Хорошо, что дошли сами. Мне нужно было решить, что бы убедиться, что мой метод правильный :)